# different placements for ngb attributes

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I have an input that has a tooltip and a dropdown attached to it using `ngb` attributes:

```
<input 
  placement="right" 
  ngbTooltip="Search" 
  [ngbTypeahead]="search" 
/>
```

the problem is, I want the tooltip to display to the right of the input but I want the dropdown that appears for `typeahead` to display below the input. Is it possible to have multiple placements on the same element so each has it's own position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the input element in an inline container, like a `span`, on which you set the tooltip:

```
<span ngbTooltip="Tooltip at the right" placement="right" >
  <input [ngbTypeahead]="search" placement="bottom" />
</span>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbmn9e) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

No. But you can workaround the problem by

- using a placeholder rather than a tooltip. That looks more appropriate to me (see the search text field at the top of this page)
- wrapping the input with a span, and adding the tooltip on the span rather than the input